# Tabela responsiva com scroll caso tela seja menor que os dados

Tags: html, css, table, layout-responsivo

estou tendo dificuldades em um certo ponto responsivo do site que estou criando. Preciso de um norte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem o menu lateral está fechado, ocupando menos espaço. Como minha div possui tamanho fixo ela permanece com o tamanho.

- Se eu colocar um width 100% na div a tabela perde o scroll interno,
  porque os dados farão ela se esticar até ficar gigantesco e a página
  em si ganha um scroll lateral ficando algo inviável

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Caso eu coloque uma classe de colunas responsivas o texto vai se comprimir demais ficando algo ilegível devido a quantidade numerosa de colunas
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.ScrollDiv {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative !important;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Título da página</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ScrollDiv">
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Frutas</th>
          <th>Verduras</th>
          <th>Grãos</th>
          <th>Frutas</th>
          <th>Verduras</th>
          <th>Grãos</th>
          <th>Frutas</th>
          <th>Verduras</th>
          <th>Grãos</th>
          <th>Frutas</th>
          <th>Verduras</th>
          <th>Grãos</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Maçã</td>
          <td>Alface</td>
          <td>Arroz</td>
          <td>Maçã</td>
          <td>Alface</td>
          <td>Arroz</td>
          <td>Maçã</td>
          <td>Alface</td>
          <td>Arroz</td>
          <td>Maçã</td>
          <td>Alface</td>
          <td>Arroz</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
          <td>Laranja</td>
          <td>Beterraba</td>
          <td>Trigo</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

No snippet não coloquei o menu lateral mas ele ficaria lado a lado com conteudo da page no caso a table. Existe algum js ou css que faça a table se adequar ao tamanho da tela? Tamanhos fixos não seriam interessantes pois preciso de uma certa responsividade.

Acredito que a solução seria alterar a div que abriga a table. Porém não sei como deixar ela responsiva devido ao menu lateral.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link: https://codepen.io/AllThingsSmitty/pen/MyqmdM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara usa um `container flex` para colocar o menu e o container da tabela dentro, no container que vai receber a tabela dentro coloca `flex:1`, basicamente é isso

Repare que o `scoll horizontal` é no *container* da `Table` e não na página

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue um protótipo básico para te ajudar

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
  
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: gold;
  display: inline-block;
}
main {
  display: flex;
}
section {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
aside {
  background: green;
}
ul {
  display: none;
}
#icon:checked + ul {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <nav>
    <label for="icon">menu</label>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <aside>
      <input type="checkbox" id="icon" type="button" value="" hidden>
      <ul>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>20</li>
        <li>30</li>
        <li>40</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <section>
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
            <th>Frutas</th>
            <th>Verduras</th>
            <th>Grãos</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
            <td>Maçã</td>
            <td>Alface</td>
            <td>Arroz</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  </main>
<script>

</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```